# How to filter opposite duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, multiple-columns

There is a table with following columns:

```
ID Parent Child
1  A      B
2  B      A
3  C      D
4  E      F
5  D      C
...
```

How to get the entries once where columns Parent+Child is the same as Child+Parent?

E.g. entries with ID 1 and 2 are the same when combining their columns as mentioned. So the result should be just one entry either that one with ID 1 or 2

So the result set should look like this:

```
ID Parent Child
1  A      B
3  C      D
4  E      F
...
```

Each entry which would be duplicated when combining parent and child or child and parent should not be part of the result.

Further information: the columns are representing relationships between tables. So if there is a relationship from parent to child, i don't need another entry with the relationship from child to parent.

My own conclusion is that this problem can't be solved just with an SQL-Statement and needs a loop, but i hope someone's out there to teach me better. 
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
My minimal example didn't consider that the values in each column aren't as easy as i wrote. They are generated through (replace(newid(),'-','') and are guid's afaik. So, i am not really sure if it is possible to compare them with usual operators like <,>,= and if the newest newid() is really > a previous newid()?
Is there another way to solve this problem?
In real the table looks like this:

```
ID                                 Parent                             Child
6C57C330EB5A4DF8BC245A245569A97C   FF42FB32F3FC463EA3366FAB7425E706   7FEF3100E5F149EFB27967F0BE95FFC8
9AD0035D04FA4695AE7854F4BE29FF60   7FEF3100E5F149EFB27967F0BE95FFC8   FF42FB32F3FC463EA3366FAB7425E706
```

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by set operations, for example:

```
 SELECT parent, child FROM YourTable 
 INTERSECT
 SELECT child, parent FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately it is not that easy. The result of this just leaves line with ID 4 (see above).

Comment: sorry, I've now changed it to intersection

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ID),
       CASE WHEN Parent < Child THEN Parent ELSE Child END,
       CASE WHEN Parent >= Child THEN Parent ELSE Child END
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Parent < Child THEN Parent ELSE Child END,
         CASE WHEN Parent >= Child THEN Parent ELSE Child END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this like that:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.Parent > t.Child
```

This works as follow : In each pair(unless they can be identical , which i doubt) one of them must be bigger then the other, therefore - this condition will return only 1 of each pair.